# Maze generation - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, maze

I tried generate maze with two entries at the opposite sides.

But when I trying to run this test program I catch `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at maze.variation.MyMaze.generateMaze(MyMaze.java:61)
    at maze.variation.MyMaze.generateMaze(MyMaze.java:63)
    at maze.variation.MyMaze.generateMaze(MyMaze.java:51)
    at maze.variation.MyMaze.generateMaze(MyMaze.java:51)
    at maze.variation.MyMaze.generateMaze(MyMaze.java:51)
    at maze.variation.MyMaze.generateMaze(MyMaze.java:51)
    at maze.variation.MyMaze.generateMaze(MyMaze.java:35)
    at maze.variation.MyMaze.<init>(MyMaze.java:14)
    at maze.variation.MyMaze.main(MyMaze.java:137)
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. It's some easy failures, but I can't find weak place.

**Code:**

```
public class MyMaze {
    private int dimension; // dimension of maze
    private char[][] grid;
    private boolean[][] marked;
    private boolean[][] visited;
    private boolean done = false;

    public MyMaze(int aDimension) {
        dimension = aDimension;
        grid = new char[dimension][dimension];
        init();
        generateMaze();
    }

    private void init() {
        // initialize border cells as already visited
        visited = new boolean[dimension + 2][dimension + 2];
        for (int x = 0; x < dimension + 2; x++)
            visited[x][0] = visited[x][dimension + 1] = true;
        for (int y = 0; y < dimension + 2; y++)
            visited[0][y] = visited[dimension + 1][y] = true;

        // initialze all walls as present
        visited = new boolean[dimension + 2][dimension + 2];
        marked = new boolean[dimension + 2][dimension + 2];
        for (int x = 0; x < dimension + 2; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < dimension + 2; y++)
                marked[x][y] = true;
    }

    // generate the maze starting from lower left
    private void generateMaze() {
        generateMaze(1, 1);
    }

    // generate the maze
    private void generateMaze(int x, int y) {
        visited[x][y] = true;

        // while there is an unvisited neighbor
        while (!visited[x][y + 1] || !visited[x + 1][y] || !visited[x][y - 1]
                || !visited[x - 1][y]) {

            // pick random neighbor
            while (true) {
                double r = Math.random();
                if (r < 0.25 && !visited[x][y + 1]) {
                    marked[x][y] = marked[x][y + 1] = false;
                    generateMaze(x, y + 1);            // 51 line
                    break;
                } else if (r >= 0.25 && r < 0.50 && !visited[x + 1][y]) {
                    marked[x][y] = marked[x + 1][y] = false;
                    generateMaze(x + 1, y);
                    break;
                } else if (r >= 0.5 && r < 0.75 && !visited[x][y - 1]) {
                    marked[x][y] = marked[x][y - 1] = false;
                    generateMaze(x, y - 1);
                    break;
                } else if (r >= 0.75 && r < 1.00 && !visited[x - 1][y]) { // 61 line
                    marked[x][y] = marked[x - 1][y] = false;
                    generateMaze(x - 1, y);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // solve the maze starting from the start state
    public void solve() {
        for (int x = 1; x <= dimension; x++)
            for (int y = 1; y <= dimension; y++)
                visited[x][y] = false;
        done = false;
        solve(1, 1);
    }    

    // draw the maze
    public void draw() {

        for (int x = 1; x <= dimension; x++) {
            for (int y = 1; y <= dimension; y++) {
                if (marked[x][y]) {
                    grid[x][y] = '*';                       
                }
            }
        }
            System.out.print(this.grid);
    }

    /**
     * Overridden method to generate a human readable maze state.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(1024);
        for (int x = 0; x < this.dimension; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < this.dimension; y++) {
                sb.append(this.grid[x][y]);
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int userDimension = 40;
        MyMaze maze = new MyMaze(userDimension);
        maze.draw();
    }
}
```

I don't know how to find solution for creating two entries at opposite sides (north and south) and they need to have connection to maze. Any suggestions?

- ***How to solve this error trouble?***

**Edit:**

I added this check into while loop:

```
    // pick random neighbor
    while (true) {
       if (x == 0 || x == 1 || y == 0 || y == 1) continue;
       // method's rest
```

It looks ok now.If you running this code you'll find no output. But it should be.
***Why this doesn't print maze correctly?***

Comment: Can you please set a marker on the line 61 ?

Comment: your generateMaze method searches for unvisited neighbors. For this it accesses the array positions around, but it does not check if you are already at the border of your maze, thus you access the array at an invalid position (-1)

Comment: @Matthias How to circumvents this slippery place?

Comment: @nazar_art before accessing the array, check if your index is < 0 or > array.length -1. If this is the case, you are already at the border of your maze and there is no neighbor on this side. You have to check this for both dimensions of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I notice in your script is in `init()` you initialize `visited` and use for loops to initialize it, and then immediately after you initialize again and don't set any values in it to true. This I think causes the walls to become eliminated. Then later on in the script during generation it becomes possible to be at a wall because none are marked visited initially. Then during maze generation since it's at the 'edge' of the array it may try to reference a cell outside the array which is your error. So remove the second initialization of `visited`

Another thing you should be wary of is the potential of an infinite while loop. The while loop after determining that there was a neighbor has the potential to continually not pick the right r to get the neighbor in theory, but it does have the potential to slow down tremendously. Instead, I would find all neighbors, put them into an `ArrayList and then pick a random one. See source below.

Another error exists in the `draw` method. The for loop should iterate with the conditions being `x < this.dimension` and `y < this.dimension` instead of `<=`. Otherwise you'll get ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error.

Finally the `println` method we'll print a less than valuable representation of the array that contains no information of its contents. Do this instead:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(this.grid));
```

---

Here's my finalized version of the code. There is an inner class `Cell` and a field `Cell[][] cells` in `MyMaze` which replaced the need for bridges and the original variables for tracking the state of cells. The outer 2 rows and columns are removed because the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is caught by `getCell` and returns `null` when out of bounds. The idea of generation has been altered to prevent excessive calling to avoid getting a stack overflow on large boards. Boards can be rectangular now. The solver is implemented based on A-star algorithm. The output has been updated to produce meaningful representation. The "X" are walls and the "*" is the solved path. It is commented so should be able to read through what's going on

Here is my finalized source :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Random;

public class MyMaze {
  private int dimensionX, dimensionY; // dimension of maze
  private int gridDimensionX, gridDimensionY; // dimension of output grid
  private char[][] grid; // output grid
  private Cell[][] cells; // 2d array of Cells
  private Random random = new Random(); // The random object

  // initialize with x and y the same
  public MyMaze(int aDimension) {
      // Initialize
      this(aDimension, aDimension);
  }
  // constructor
  public MyMaze(int xDimension, int yDimension) {
      dimensionX = xDimension;
      dimensionY = yDimension;
      gridDimensionX = xDimension * 4 + 1;
      gridDimensionY = yDimension * 2 + 1;
      grid = new char[gridDimensionX][gridDimensionY];
      init();
      generateMaze();
  }

  private void init() {
      // create cells
      cells = new Cell[dimensionX][dimensionY];
      for (int x = 0; x < dimensionX; x++) {
          for (int y = 0; y < dimensionY; y++) {
              cells[x][y] = new Cell(x, y, false); // create cell (see Cell constructor)
          }
      }
  }

  // inner class to represent a cell
  private class Cell {
    int x, y; // coordinates
    // cells this cell is connected to
    ArrayList<Cell> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();
    // solver: if already used
    boolean visited = false;
    // solver: the Cell before this one in the path
    Cell parent = null;
    // solver: if used in last attempt to solve path
    boolean inPath = false;
    // solver: distance travelled this far
    double travelled;
    // solver: projected distance to end
    double projectedDist;
    // impassable cell
    boolean wall = true;
    // if true, has yet to be used in generation
    boolean open = true;
    // construct Cell at x, y
    Cell(int x, int y) {
        this(x, y, true);
    }
    // construct Cell at x, y and with whether it isWall
    Cell(int x, int y, boolean isWall) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.wall = isWall;
    }
    // add a neighbor to this cell, and this cell as a neighbor to the other
    void addNeighbor(Cell other) {
        if (!this.neighbors.contains(other)) { // avoid duplicates
            this.neighbors.add(other);
        }
        if (!other.neighbors.contains(this)) { // avoid duplicates
            other.neighbors.add(this);
        }
    }
    // used in updateGrid()
    boolean isCellBelowNeighbor() {
        return this.neighbors.contains(new Cell(this.x, this.y + 1));
    }
    // used in updateGrid()
    boolean isCellRightNeighbor() {
        return this.neighbors.contains(new Cell(this.x + 1, this.y));
    }
    // useful Cell representation
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Cell(%s, %s)", x, y);
    }
    // useful Cell equivalence
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (!(other instanceof Cell)) return false;
        Cell otherCell = (Cell) other;
        return (this.x == otherCell.x && this.y == otherCell.y);
    }
    // should be overridden with equals
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // random hash code method designed to be usually unique
        return this.x + this.y * 256;
    }
  }
  // generate from upper left (In computing the y increases down often)
  private void generateMaze() {
      generateMaze(0, 0);
  }
  // generate the maze from coordinates x, y
  private void generateMaze(int x, int y) {
      generateMaze(getCell(x, y)); // generate from Cell
  }
  private void generateMaze(Cell startAt) {
      // don't generate from cell not there
      if (startAt == null) return;
      startAt.open = false; // indicate cell closed for generation
      ArrayList<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<>();
      cells.add(startAt);

      while (!cells.isEmpty()) {
          Cell cell;
          // this is to reduce but not completely eliminate the number
          //   of long twisting halls with short easy to detect branches
          //   which results in easy mazes
          if (random.nextInt(10)==0)
              cell = cells.remove(random.nextInt(cells.size()));
          else cell = cells.remove(cells.size() - 1);
          // for collection
          ArrayList<Cell> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();
          // cells that could potentially be neighbors
          Cell[] potentialNeighbors = new Cell[]{
              getCell(cell.x + 1, cell.y),
              getCell(cell.x, cell.y + 1),
              getCell(cell.x - 1, cell.y),
              getCell(cell.x, cell.y - 1)
          };
          for (Cell other : potentialNeighbors) {
              // skip if outside, is a wall or is not opened
              if (other==null || other.wall || !other.open) continue;
              neighbors.add(other);
          }
          if (neighbors.isEmpty()) continue;
          // get random cell
          Cell selected = neighbors.get(random.nextInt(neighbors.size()));
          // add as neighbor
          selected.open = false; // indicate cell closed for generation
          cell.addNeighbor(selected);
          cells.add(cell);
          cells.add(selected);
      }
  }
  // used to get a Cell at x, y; returns null out of bounds
  public Cell getCell(int x, int y) {
      try {
          return cells[x][y];
      } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) { // catch out of bounds
          return null;
      }
  }

  public void solve() {
      // default solve top left to bottom right
      this.solve(0, 0, dimensionX - 1, dimensionY -1);
  }
  // solve the maze starting from the start state (A-star algorithm)
  public void solve(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
      // re initialize cells for path finding
      for (Cell[] cellrow : this.cells) {
          for (Cell cell : cellrow) {
              cell.parent = null;
              cell.visited = false;
              cell.inPath = false;
              cell.travelled = 0;
              cell.projectedDist = -1;
          }
      }
      // cells still being considered
      ArrayList<Cell> openCells = new ArrayList<>();
      // cell being considered
      Cell endCell = getCell(endX, endY);
      if (endCell == null) return; // quit if end out of bounds
      { // anonymous block to delete start, because not used later
          Cell start = getCell(startX, startY);
          if (start == null) return; // quit if start out of bounds
          start.projectedDist = getProjectedDistance(start, 0, endCell);
          start.visited = true;
          openCells.add(start);
      }
      boolean solving = true;
      while (solving) {
          if (openCells.isEmpty()) return; // quit, no path
          // sort openCells according to least projected distance
          Collections.sort(openCells, new Comparator<Cell>(){
              @Override
              public int compare(Cell cell1, Cell cell2) {
                  double diff = cell1.projectedDist - cell2.projectedDist;
                  if (diff > 0) return 1;
                  else if (diff < 0) return -1;
                  else return 0;
              }
          });
          Cell current = openCells.remove(0); // pop cell least projectedDist
          if (current == endCell) break; // at end
          for (Cell neighbor : current.neighbors) {
              double projDist = getProjectedDistance(neighbor,
                      current.travelled + 1, endCell);
              if (!neighbor.visited || // not visited yet
                      projDist < neighbor.projectedDist) { // better path
                  neighbor.parent = current;
                  neighbor.visited = true;
                  neighbor.projectedDist = projDist;
                  neighbor.travelled = current.travelled + 1;
                  if (!openCells.contains(neighbor))
                      openCells.add(neighbor);
              }
          }
      }
      // create path from end to beginning
      Cell backtracking = endCell;
      backtracking.inPath = true;
      while (backtracking.parent != null) {
          backtracking = backtracking.parent;
          backtracking.inPath = true;
      }
  }
  // get the projected distance
  // (A star algorithm consistent)
  public double getProjectedDistance(Cell current, double travelled, Cell end) {
      return travelled + Math.abs(current.x - end.x) + 
              Math.abs(current.y - current.x);
  }

  // draw the maze
  public void updateGrid() {
      char backChar = ' ', wallChar = 'X', cellChar = ' ', pathChar = '*';
      // fill background
      for (int x = 0; x < gridDimensionX; x ++) {
          for (int y = 0; y < gridDimensionY; y ++) {
              grid[x][y] = backChar;
          }
      }
      // build walls
      for (int x = 0; x < gridDimensionX; x ++) {
          for (int y = 0; y < gridDimensionY; y ++) {
              if (x % 4 == 0 || y % 2 == 0)
                  grid[x][y] = wallChar;
          }
      }
      // make meaningful representation
      for (int x = 0; x < dimensionX; x++) {
          for (int y = 0; y < dimensionY; y++) {
              Cell current = getCell(x, y);
              int gridX = x * 4 + 2, gridY = y * 2 + 1;
              if (current.inPath) {
                  grid[gridX][gridY] = pathChar;
                  if (current.isCellBelowNeighbor())
                      if (getCell(x, y + 1).inPath) {
                          grid[gridX][gridY + 1] = pathChar;
                          grid[gridX + 1][gridY + 1] = backChar;
                          grid[gridX - 1][gridY + 1] = backChar;
                      } else {
                          grid[gridX][gridY + 1] = cellChar;
                          grid[gridX + 1][gridY + 1] = backChar;
                          grid[gridX - 1][gridY + 1] = backChar;
                      }
                  if (current.isCellRightNeighbor())
                      if (getCell(x + 1, y).inPath) {
                          grid[gridX + 2][gridY] = pathChar;
                          grid[gridX + 1][gridY] = pathChar;
                          grid[gridX + 3][gridY] = pathChar;
                      } else {
                          grid[gridX + 2][gridY] = cellChar;
                          grid[gridX + 1][gridY] = cellChar;
                          grid[gridX + 3][gridY] = cellChar;
                      }
              } else {
                  grid[gridX][gridY] = cellChar;
                  if (current.isCellBelowNeighbor()) {
                      grid[gridX][gridY + 1] = cellChar;
                      grid[gridX + 1][gridY + 1] = backChar;
                      grid[gridX - 1][gridY + 1] = backChar;
                  }
                  if (current.isCellRightNeighbor()) {
                      grid[gridX + 2][gridY] = cellChar;
                      grid[gridX + 1][gridY] = cellChar;
                      grid[gridX + 3][gridY] = cellChar;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }

  // simply prints the map
  public void draw() {
      System.out.print(this);
  }
  // forms a meaningful representation
  @Override
  public String toString() {
      updateGrid();
      String output = "";
      for (int y = 0; y < gridDimensionY; y++) {
          for (int x = 0; x < gridDimensionX; x++) {
              output += grid[x][y];
          }
          output += "\n";
      }
      return output;
  }

  // run it
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      MyMaze maze = new MyMaze(20);
      maze.solve();
      System.out.print(maze);
  }
}
```

Comment: As I understood this `..I replaced everything except the first line of ` should be into `init()`?

Comment: @nazar_art No, in the `init()` method the only thing I did was remove the second `visited = new boolean[dimension+2][dimension+2];`. Additionally, the codeblock in my answer is currently the entire body of my `generateMaze(int, int)`. I can post my modified source if you want, it works for me.

Comment: It will be really helpful.

Comment: @nazar_art I've updated the post with the source is there are some updates since the original post.

Comment: Can I remember that you forgot about this method `solve(1, 1);`. But I very appreciate your work (output looks a little bit weird).

Comment: Well majorly I was focusing on getting the logic to work. But I can implement better representation and the solve method (assuming the endpoint us the opposite corner), but I'd have to suggest a new (possibly inner) class called `Cell` as described above to replace all the `int[2]` describing points.

Comment: main function is generate maze and find solution through this maze

Comment: Kind of a different question, but I'll update the code when I finish implementing the solver.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the finalized version of the code including solver and updated output.

Comment: Really very cool. Can I clarify few details: - Can we make enter and exit at outside wall and - I tried make some easy update with this static method `private static MyMaze askUserInput() {
  int X = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
    .showInputDialog("Enter dimention of the maze: "));

  System.exit(0);
  return new MyMaze(X);
 }` and change one line into `main` to `MyMaze maze = askUserInput();` but it didn't work. And I couldn't find why exactly this happen?

Comment: It's `System.exit(0);`. This quits the entire program. If the intent of `System.exit` is to close the `JOptionPane` it is not necessary. The `JOptionPane` automatically closes itself when the user enters. You may want to catch the possible `NumberFormatException` and either keep asking, output a message like "Not a number" or quit cleanly without an unhandled exception.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class which will store the maze, and write a getter that is protected against `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
class Maze {
int maze[][];
int getValue(int x, int y){
  if (x<0 || x>maze.length) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (y<0 || y>maze[0].length) {
    return 0;
  }
  return maze[x][y];
}
```

Also provide a setter working in a similar fashion.

Repeat the same work for each 2d array member of your maze.

BTW: consider using enums instead of chars - you'll find they're much more powerful.
edit: enum usage code sample

```
enum Tile {
  WALL('*', false), EMPTY(' ', true), WATER('~', false), GRASS('_', true);

  private Tile (char representation, boolean passable) {
    this.representation=representation;
    this.passable=passable;
  }

  char representation;
  boolean passable;

  public char getRepresentation() { return representation; }
  public boolean isPassable() { return passable; }
}

Tile maze[][];
```

Comment: @nazar_art added sample

Comment: Can you explain more? You wrote make smt as `private int[][] maze;
 private boolean[][] marked;
 private boolean[][] visited;` + getters & setters.

Answer (score 1):

At line 30, in the very beginning of `generateMaze(int x, int y)`, add a `System.err.println("dimension is " + dimension + " x is " + x + " y is " + y);`

In the error console you will probably see that x or y is outside or close to the boundary at some time. Note that you can't interate too close to the outer boundary since you do direct accesses to neighbors at lines 49, 50, 53, 54, 57, 58, 61 and 62.

Comment: I tried add `if (x == 0 || x == 1 || y == 0 || y == 1) continue;` into while. Only `dimension is 40 x is 1 y is 1` is missed, how to catch this condition?